# Incluir todos os objetos filhos (navigation properies) na busca do entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Gostaria de saber se é possível buscar o objeto completamente preenchido sem precisar chamar o `include` especificando cada **objeto filho (com seus respectivos filhos)** da minha classe.

Atualmente, estou fazendo assim:

```
dbContext.Ocorrencia.Include("Pessoa")
                    .Include("Endereco")
                    .Include("Veiculo")
                    .Where(c => c.id == @id).ToList();
```

Neste caso, cada objeto filho terá também seu próprio objeto filho, gerando uma cascata. Sendo assim, não estou achando elegante esta forma de ir incluindo item a item.

> Existe uma forma de inserir todos os "filhos" em um único comando.
>   Como se existisse um `.IncludeAll()` por exemplo.

Não achei nenhuma referência que me atendesse bem.

Comment: Ha uma resposta para a sua pergunta neste link: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30839/dbsett-includeall-method?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

Só gostaria de comentar algo despretenciosamente. Quando fazemos uma pesquisa no banco, devemos sempre **retornar o menor escopo possível e com apenas as informações necessárias** para aquela tela ou método. Há realmente necessidade de um `select * from table` e ainda incluir tudo de todos os filhos?

Se você não tem controle sobre a quantidade recursiva de filhos possíveis, você pode ter o problema de n+1, uma espécie de loop infinito. É justamente por este tipo de paradigma que o `lazyload` deve ser usado com muito critério.

Não conheço seu cenário, mas num modelo lógico mais simples, eu iria no banco apenas para buscar as informações necessárias e somente quando elas forem realmente necessárias.

Answer (score 0):

Não existe um `IncludeAll()`, porém o `ObjectQuery<T>.Include` é um all include, logo se você colocar um `ObjectQuery.Include(Pessoa.Sexo)` você estará carregando tanto Pessoa como Sexo ao mesmo tempo.

Outra abordagem seria ativar o Lazy Loading. O Lazy Load vai buscar todas entidades relacionadas. O problema é que ele pode carregar mais coisas do que você deseja, sendo um problema para serialização, principalmente utilizando frameworks obsoletos. Não recomendo essa abordagem, pois aparentemente o mesmo esta desabilitado no seu projeto então alguém tomou essa decisão e seria imprudente ativar sem entender os motivos dessa decisão.

Para ativar o Lazy Load, retire o virtual da propriedade que representa o relacionamento e deixe o LazyLoadingEnabled igual a verdadeiro.